# Use email/phone instead of username for authenticating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using `Congnito` user pool for storing my application users.
I am able to sign in using `username` and `password`. For my web application i have requirement to have user to be able to authenticate himself using `email/phone` as per his wish. and both `email` and `phone number` can exist at the sametime.I did some RnD and found out that i need to write some lambda function to achieve that, is there any other way to achieve it, For lamda function please help me to write it.

I am using Ruby on rails 5 for building my web application and `aws-sdk` gem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you using devise, user custom auth system

Comment: @vipin i am using devise.

Answer (score 2):

Cognito User Pools allows users to login using an 'alias' and a password. (Among other methods)

In Cognito User Pools, the term "alias" refers to a unique identifier  for a user. User Pools actually supports using usernames, emails or phone numbers as aliases.

So it sounds like your use case is actually natively supported in Cognito User Pools. As long as your use case is exactly as you've described, you shouldn't need to write any lambda function here in order to support the login flow.

You'll need to make sure that you've marked the email and phone number attributes in your User Pool's settings as "alias" values for your user pool. This ensures that each user's email and phone number is unique when they register, and as a result they can login using their email or phone number, along with their password.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html